# How to invoke a method across instances in C++

Tags: c++, oop, object, instance

I have two instances of a class Robot. When I run some method (say, `go()`) I want every instance to *go* if it is on a correct frequency. Example (for simplicity everything is in one file):

```
class Robot {
    int freqency_from;
    int freqency_to;
    bool is_going = false;

    bool isOnFrequency(int frequency) {
        return (frequency >= frequency_from && frequency <= frequency_to);
    }

public:
    Robot(int _freqency_from , int _freqency_to) {
        freqency_from = _freqency_from;
        freqency_to = _freqency_to;
    }

    void go(int frequency) {
        if (isOnFrequency(frequency)) {
            is_going = true;
        }
    }

    bool isGoing() {
        return is_going;
    }
};

int main() {
    Robot robot1 = Robot(1, 3);
    Robot robot2 = Robot(3, 5);

    cout << robot1.isGoing(); // false
    cout << robot2.isGoing(); // false

    Robot::go(1); // should be run for each and every instance of the Robot class

    cout << robot1.isGoing(); // true
    cout << robot2.isGoing(); // false

    return 0;
}
```

How to make this pseudo-code work? Is it even possible without making a vector of all instances of Robot and mapping over it?

Comment: You probably could have a static member vector of pointers to existing instances and make the `go` method static as well. But I don't think this is a good design.

Comment: This is heading towards static / "singleton" territory and seems like a code smell to me. In this case if there is something each `Robot` should do, then you should have some kind of `RobotManager` that keeps a collection of them to do various tasks with. That business logic should not be within the `Robot` class itself.

Comment: @Dan Ran a regex search for `class \w+Manager[^;]` in our codebase... 437 matching lines, ouch :)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense... I just didn't want to make a vector as stated at the end. I hoped for some built-in functionality in C++ itself. I guess I won't be able to overcome it then...

Comment: I think what you are looking for is essentially a listener/observer pattern.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon true. I am pretty new to the C++ itself, and although I know how to make it in different languages, not aware of the implementation in C++. Gonna research that though! Thanks!

Comment: @CzajkowskiDariusz You are welcome! That's basically the same thing suggested by CoryKramer. You are going to find plenty of examples of that.

Comment: Yeah, I went for the manager class. Looks pretty nice :) Have a look if you want: https://pastebin.com/hseYhqwV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a regular old loop?  Just store your robots in a container and iterate over it.

```
vector<Robot> robots;    
robots.emplace_back(1, 3);
robots.emplace_back(3, 5);

for (auto& robot : robots)
{
  cout << robot.isGoing();
  robot.go(1);
  cout << robot.isGoing();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm gonna do. Wasn't aware of the `.emplace_back()` method, though. Sweet! :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you had explicitly asked for something other than vector.  `list`, `map`, and `set` will all work too, of course.  But you are stuck managing a collection of some sort.  There's no secret sauce to enumerate instances without one.

Comment: I have totally nothing against vectors. I actually really like them :) I just thought there may be some 'global' method that would be run on every instance of the class. But all of that makes total sense. Thanks! :)

Comment: BTW, this is what I ended up with: https://pastebin.com/hseYhqwV. Have a look if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Robot::go(1);
```

> ***should be run for each and every instance of the Robot class***

not really, go is not a static method...

you need an instance like robot1 or robot2 in order to command that robot,

if you want to do that all the robots react to the go function then declare then 
consider defining that method static

Comment: Correct, but if I declare it static, it won't be able to change/get objects' properties, no?

Comment: @CzajkowskiDariusz yes you are right, OP will need to define well what belongs to a  static content and what doesnt

Comment: Right, but if I make a `frequency`/`is_going` property a static one, then it won't be able to be set in the constructor... :/ I guess the only option is to make a vector of pointers to all instances and then map over them by running the `go()` method on each, one by one.